# map saved in orbslam2

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi:

i want to save a map in the system of orbslam2. But after i run the launch and the map is build, then the window is closed. So i can't get the map saved. I want to know whether the system have the functions of save the map.Can you tell me how to get the map saved？

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230284/map-saved-in-orbslam2/) by [xiqing](https://answers.ros.org/users/24127/xiqing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This link may be helped youhttps://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2/issues/19,I used the [http://recherche.enac.fr/~drouin/slam/orbslam2/poine_orbslam2_04_07_16.tgz](http://recherche.enac.fr/%7Edrouin/slam/orbslam2/poine_orbslam2_04_07_16.tgz) which is wrote by @Michael and I can save the map and load the map successfully.(Note:when you use this package you should add the camera.with and camera.height in your yaml file). Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Yuxi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27784/yuxi/) with karma: 18 on 2017-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0